# How to support multiple user bases in SAML-based SSO without synchronizing them?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, federation

I am reading about SAML2.0 based federation as it is supposed to apply for SSO in the current setting:

- In application *A* a user has credentials *email/password1*
- In application *B*, the same user has credentials *username/password2*
- If the user logs in at *A*, he/she should also be logged in at *B*

SAML v2.0 seems to be a good choice in this situation:

- central identity provider (IdP), maybe *A* or *B* or a third party *C*.
- *A* and *B* would be service providers (SP)
- if user tries to access *A*, *A* would request SAML assertions from the IdP containing *email*
- if user tries to access *B*, *B* would request SAML assertions from the IdP containing *username*
- But if the user is authenticated in *A*, how should he/she be logged in *B* (for which *username*)?

Documents about SAML (e.g. here: https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/11785/sstc-saml-exec-overview-2.0-draft-06.pdf) pretend that SAML allows SSO without requiring to synchronize or migrate identities between all players.

However, I don't see, how all this should work without maintaining and merging all credentials of the same subject in the central IdP which in fact is a kind of synchronization.

If you have the impression that I am quite confused about SAML v2.0 capibilities, you are right ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a service provider, SAML doesn't allow you to do away with a user store usually. This is because it's a method by which you externalize authentication only. Most service providers have a 1-to-1 relationship of users in their store, to users at their identity providers. However, it may not need to be this way, as you can do a one-to-many federation as well. I'll expand shortly.

In the one-to-one, you will generally use either a "just in time" provisioning method, or an out of band user synchronization method. The just in time is usually done via attributes provided in the assertion, and is done by the SP when it realizes that the user that has been presented in the assertion doesn't exist the application's user store. The out of band method is some other process, a directory synchronization, etc. A user gets add to the IdP's store, and some process adds that user to the SP store, via flat file, XML, etc.

Having said that, depending on the type of service provider, you could do a one-to-many, and count solely on the attributes provided to support the needs of the application. Let's say you run a printing operation. You could agree on having the IdP send a cost center along with other attributes for the user (name, number, email, etc.). Then all the data is stored just on that print job, with the Cost Center sent back during billing. I will say, I've only seen a couple of instances of one-to-many federations in my career.

I don't think your example is quite right - meaning you didn't ask it quite right, but then again, you're not familiar enough, maybe.

Let's presume the following:

- Service Provider X needs username
- Service Provider Y needs email
- Identity Provider A can provide all of these from their user store

The user shows up at SPX. SPX says "based on the url you went to (idpa.serviceproviderx.com), I know you need to be sent over to IdPA." and redirects the user to IdPA. IdPA authenticates the user, looks at its  "attribute contract" to determine that it's supposed to send username to SPX, and redirects the user with that attribute as its "subject" in the assertion. SPX consumes that assertion, and can map the user back to where they are supposed to go.

Now, the user is browsing through their portal, and clicks a link that starts an SSO to SPY. The user is already authenticated to IdPA, so IdPA checks it's contract and sees it's supposed to use email with SPY. It creates an assertion for SPY with email as the subject, and redirects the user to SPY for consumption of the assertion and connection to the application.

Now, in both those instances, the IdP has to determine what to send to complete the contract with the SP - and it always will. This is based on a "contract" - some form of agreement between the IdP and SP that has to be supported by administrators of both systems.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped to enlight the SAML capabilities a bit. BTW, I also found this technical overview which supports your statements: https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the main missunderstanding here is how authentication works in SAML. I SAML the IDP authenticates the user. This means, you have no crederial store at the SP.

SSO in SAML happends at the IDP. If the user has already signed in once at the IDP the user is just sent back to the SP without authenticating.

Comment: yes, I understand that authenticaten is done at the IP. Then a SAML assertion containing the email in case of A or the username in case of B. The applications require this to know, which user is authenticated, for displaying the account data of that user, right. My point is, that the IP needs to know the relation between the user of A and B for SSO and I don't see how this can work without having synchronized both user stores.